# How do I control already configured Raspberry Pi without paired BT mouse?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi that has been configured and now I have to set it up and running, however I have no access to it with mouse nor keyboard. How do I control it to set it up correctly with my configurations while considering that I have no access to it with a non-BT-mouse or such?

Comment: You can SSH to it...or VNC.

Comment: Is there solution that doesn't required any setup for Raspberry Pi's behalf? I found only solutions with a rudimentary configuration on Rasperry Pi's half but like I said, I have no access to do even those configurations.

Comment: Also, you can connect a Serial2USB converter to the PI and send your commands throw serial Debug port.